# How to rearrange a two dimensional array

Tags: c

I want to assign the values in one array to another, but in a different 
order. For example the original array would be:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
8  9  10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

And the desired array is:

```
8  11 14 3 6  16 19
9  12 1  4 7  17 20 
10 13 2  5 15 18 21
```

How would I do this? In the code below I moved a selected row to the center, then assigned each array individually. I can't figure out a better way.

```
int main()
{
int decide, i, j, k;
int save[3][7];
int shuffle[3][7];
int arr[3][7] = {
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
                {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 
                {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}
            };

printf("Select a number between 1 and 21\n\n0-GroupA (1 - 7))\n1-GroupB ( 8 - 14)\n2-GroupC (15 - 21)\n\n");

for(k = 0 ; k < 1 ; ++k)
{
    printf("Select which group the number falls into:");
    scanf("%d", &decide);

    for(j = 0 ; j < 7 ; ++j)
    {/*moves selected row to middle row of array*/
        save[0][j] = arr[1][j]; 
        arr[1][j] = arr[decide][j];
        arr[decide][j] = save[0][j];
    }

    /*this is a horrible method*/
    shuffle[0][0] = arr[0][0];
    shuffle[1][0] = arr[0][1];
    shuffle[2][0] = arr[0][2];
    shuffle[0][1] = arr[0][3];
    shuffle[1][1] = arr[0][4];
    shuffle[2][1] = arr[0][5];
    shuffle[0][2] = arr[0][6];
    shuffle[1][2] = arr[1][0];
    shuffle[2][2] = arr[1][1];
    shuffle[0][3] = arr[1][2];
    shuffle[1][3] = arr[1][3];
    shuffle[2][3] = arr[1][4];
    shuffle[0][4] = arr[1][5];
    shuffle[1][4] = arr[1][6];
    shuffle[2][4] = arr[2][0];
    shuffle[0][5] = arr[2][1];
    shuffle[1][5] = arr[2][2];
    shuffle[2][5] = arr[2][3];
    shuffle[0][6] = arr[2][4];
    shuffle[1][6] = arr[2][5];
    shuffle[2][6] = arr[2][6];

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to shuffle this way?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The logic behind your shuffle isn't intuitively obvious.  How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Do you just wnat to randomly re-assign them?

Comment: @Makogan: It isn't quite random, but it isn't obvious either.  Starting at 8, it skips 2 spaces along the row, then jumps back a row, and then jumps down to the bottom row, and then it starts skipping those entries already moved.  But the full logic isn't obvious to me. I suppose the sequence of assignments might give a better clue about what is intended — but there should be some sort of explanation in words.

Comment: The logic seem to be swap the first two rows, then transpose. Except it's not a square matrix.

Comment: I am trying to make a short game based of some mathematical sequences. The user picks a number and then inputs the GROUP that number belongs to (does not input the number itself). You then move the sequence containing the number to the center of the array and shuffle. Do this three times and the number the user picked (but did not confirm) will land in the second series in the 4th slot.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: The description doesn't include the detail about selecting a row at runtime and moving it to the middle, and doesn't include the crucial detail about which number is entered as `decide` (it is probably 1, but we shouldn't have to guess).

Comment: Please add the missing information to the question, not to the comments.  The `for (k = 0; k < 1; k++)` loop is odd; it iterates once.  What's the benefit of this loop?

Comment: Ultimately this loop will run 3 times but I need a better way to shuffle the arrays before I can keep looping.

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 7

int main(void){
    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 
        {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}
    };
    int result[ROWS][COLS];
    int order[ROWS] = {1, 0, 2};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(**arr);//number of elements
    int r = 0, c = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    while(n--){
        result[r++][c] = arr[order[i]][j++];
        if(r == ROWS){
            r = 0;
            c += 1;
        }
        if(j == COLS){
            j = 0;
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    //check print
    for(r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < COLS; ++c)
            printf("%-2d ", result[r][c]);
        puts("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transposition part can be done like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Sequence2D
{
    int idx_slow;
    int idx_fast;
    int max_slow;
    int max_fast;
} Sequence2D;

static inline void next2D(Sequence2D *seq)
{
    if (++seq->idx_fast == seq->max_fast)
    {
        seq->idx_fast = 0;
        if (++seq->idx_slow == seq->max_slow)
            seq->idx_slow = 0;
    }
}

static inline void dump2D(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, int data[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            printf("%3d", data[r][c]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

enum { ROWS = 3, COLS = 7 };

int main(void)
{
    int src[ROWS][COLS] =
    {
        {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7 },
        {  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 },
        { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 },
    };
    int dst[ROWS][COLS];
    Sequence2D dst2D = { 0, 0, COLS, ROWS };
    Sequence2D src2D = { 0, 0, ROWS, COLS };

    dump2D("Source", ROWS, COLS, src);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS; i++)
    {
        dst[dst2D.idx_fast][dst2D.idx_slow] = src[src2D.idx_slow][src2D.idx_fast];
        printf("dst[%d][%d] = src[%d][%d] = %d\n",
               dst2D.idx_fast, dst2D.idx_slow,
               src2D.idx_slow, src2D.idx_fast,
               dst[dst2D.idx_fast][dst2D.idx_slow]);
        next2D(&dst2D);
        next2D(&src2D);
    }

    dump2D("Target", ROWS, COLS, dst);

    return 0;
}
```

The `Sequence2D` structure plus the `next2D()` function cycle through array indexes, changing the fast index on each call of `next2D()` and the slow index when necessary.  This saves you writing out the sequence of 21 assignments, and immediately scales to other shapes without requiring much extra work on your part.  Indeed, it would not take much to handle all the sizes as run-time inputs instead of compile-time constants.

The output of this code is:

```
Source:
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
dst[0][0] = src[0][0] = 1
dst[1][0] = src[0][1] = 2
dst[2][0] = src[0][2] = 3
dst[0][1] = src[0][3] = 4
dst[1][1] = src[0][4] = 5
dst[2][1] = src[0][5] = 6
dst[0][2] = src[0][6] = 7
dst[1][2] = src[1][0] = 8
dst[2][2] = src[1][1] = 9
dst[0][3] = src[1][2] = 10
dst[1][3] = src[1][3] = 11
dst[2][3] = src[1][4] = 12
dst[0][4] = src[1][5] = 13
dst[1][4] = src[1][6] = 14
dst[2][4] = src[2][0] = 15
dst[0][5] = src[2][1] = 16
dst[1][5] = src[2][2] = 17
dst[2][5] = src[2][3] = 18
dst[0][6] = src[2][4] = 19
dst[1][6] = src[2][5] = 20
dst[2][6] = src[2][6] = 21
Target:
  1  4  7 10 13 16 19
  2  5  8 11 14 17 20
  3  6  9 12 15 18 21
```

If you rearrange the initial matrix (`src`) according to whatever arcane rules you're using before you copy the 'transpose' of `src` into the result (`dst`), then you should be able to get the result you desire.

---

As noted, the code can be generalized rather easily using C99 and variable-length arrays:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Sequence2D
{
    int idx_slow;
    int idx_fast;
    int max_slow;
    int max_fast;
} Sequence2D;

static inline void next2D(Sequence2D *seq)
{
    if (++seq->idx_fast == seq->max_fast)
    {
        seq->idx_fast = 0;
        if (++seq->idx_slow == seq->max_slow)
            seq->idx_slow = 0;
    }
}

static inline void dump2D(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, int data[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            printf("%3d", data[r][c]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static void transpose(int rows, int cols)
{
    assert(rows * cols < 1000000);
    int src[rows][cols];
    int dst[rows][cols];
    Sequence2D dst2D = { 0, 0, cols, rows };
    Sequence2D src2D = { 0, 0, rows, cols };
    int cells = rows * cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < cells; i++)
    {
        src[src2D.idx_slow][src2D.idx_fast] = i;
        next2D(&src2D);
    }
    /* src2D is back to its initial state! */

    dump2D("Source", rows, cols, src);

    for (int i = 0; i < cells; i++)
    {
        dst[dst2D.idx_fast][dst2D.idx_slow] = src[src2D.idx_slow][src2D.idx_fast];
        printf("dst[%d][%d] = src[%d][%d] = %d\n",
               dst2D.idx_fast, dst2D.idx_slow,
               src2D.idx_slow, src2D.idx_fast,
               dst[dst2D.idx_fast][dst2D.idx_slow]);
        next2D(&dst2D);
        next2D(&src2D);
    }

    dump2D("Target", rows, cols, dst);
}

int main(void)
{
    transpose(3, 7);
    transpose(9, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

The first section of the output is the same as before; the 9x4 part looks like:

```
Source:
  0  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7
  8  9 10 11
 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27
 28 29 30 31
 32 33 34 35
dst[0][0] = src[0][0] = 0
dst[1][0] = src[0][1] = 1
dst[2][0] = src[0][2] = 2
dst[3][0] = src[0][3] = 3
dst[4][0] = src[1][0] = 4
dst[5][0] = src[1][1] = 5
dst[6][0] = src[1][2] = 6
dst[7][0] = src[1][3] = 7
dst[8][0] = src[2][0] = 8
dst[0][1] = src[2][1] = 9
dst[1][1] = src[2][2] = 10
dst[2][1] = src[2][3] = 11
dst[3][1] = src[3][0] = 12
dst[4][1] = src[3][1] = 13
dst[5][1] = src[3][2] = 14
dst[6][1] = src[3][3] = 15
dst[7][1] = src[4][0] = 16
dst[8][1] = src[4][1] = 17
dst[0][2] = src[4][2] = 18
dst[1][2] = src[4][3] = 19
dst[2][2] = src[5][0] = 20
dst[3][2] = src[5][1] = 21
dst[4][2] = src[5][2] = 22
dst[5][2] = src[5][3] = 23
dst[6][2] = src[6][0] = 24
dst[7][2] = src[6][1] = 25
dst[8][2] = src[6][2] = 26
dst[0][3] = src[6][3] = 27
dst[1][3] = src[7][0] = 28
dst[2][3] = src[7][1] = 29
dst[3][3] = src[7][2] = 30
dst[4][3] = src[7][3] = 31
dst[5][3] = src[8][0] = 32
dst[6][3] = src[8][1] = 33
dst[7][3] = src[8][2] = 34
dst[8][3] = src[8][3] = 35
Target:
  0  9 18 27
  1 10 19 28
  2 11 20 29
  3 12 21 30
  4 13 22 31
  5 14 23 32
  6 15 24 33
  7 16 25 34
  8 17 26 35
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it arcane. I figured it out with set notation.

Comment: It is/was unexplained, and while it might be obvious to you since you know what you're doing and why you're doing it, it is not obvious to those of us who don't have your detailed background knowledge of what you are trying to do.  That makes it arcane as far as I'm concerned, as an innocent bystander trying to help the cognoscenti when the cognoscenti has not yet deigned to explain clearly what they're up to.

Answer (score -1):

You can't transpose a matrix in place. That is to say, it is not possible to write a function which will take a matrix and modify it so that it is its transpose, without creating a temporary matrix of equal size. At least without some very fancy programming.

Now your task isn't exactly the transpose, but it seems to be very similar. So I wouldn't expect there to be a nice, in place solution. You must simply create a temporary, apply the mapping from input to temporary, and write the values back.

What might help is this.

```
/* swap two rows of a matrix */
void swaprows(int *mtx, int width, int height, int rowa, int rowb)
{
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<width;i++)
   {
      int temp = mtx[rowa*width+i];
      mtx[rowa*width+i] = mtx[rowb*width+i];
      mtx[rowa*width+i] = temp;
   }
} 

/* transpose a matrix */
int transpose(int *mtx, int width, int height)
{
    int *tmtx = malloc(width*height*sizeof(int));
    if(!tmtx)
       return -1;
    for(y=0;y<width;y++)
      for(x=0;x<height;x++)
        tmtx[y*height+x] = mtx[x*width+y];

    mempy(mtx, tmtx, width * height * sizeof(int));
    free(tmtx);
}


/* your logic  */

int arr[3][7] = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 
            {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}
        };

 swaprows((int *) arr, 7, 3, 0, 1);
 transpose(int *) arr, 7, 3);
```

This seems to be what you are trying to do.